# Twitter bootstrap datepicker - start date less than end date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using eternicode twitter bootstrap datepicker (https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker). Wanted to check that does this provide validation whereby the start date will always be less than end date. In my case, am just using month & year, so would need to make sure that start month selected is always less than end month selected.

Comment: Forgot to add fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/eqwWJ/2/

Comment: So what have you tried? Is something not working?

Comment: @Skelly - No, I was just curious whether the plugin itself provides such kind of behavior to implement or not. As jquery UI datepicker does provide same thing, but I am not sure about twitter bootstrap datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two datepickers instead: one for start and one for end. Then use jQuery validation to enforce the end date to be after the start date:

```
$form.validation({
    rules: {
        "formElementName": {
            afterBeginDate : true
        }
    }
});

$.validator.addMethod(
    "afterBeginDate",
    function (value, element) {
        return (
            $end.data('datepicker').getDate() - $start.data('datepicker').getDate()
        ) > 0;
    },
    "Please select another date"
);
```